# Invoke console app from windows service

Tags: c#, pdf, process, windows-services, console-application

I have a simple windows service which i need to use to invoke a console application.The console app generates pdf to print by opening the adobe reader window.Running the console app works fine to print pdf.But invoking it from service not successful.It doesnt even show up the console window where i log events.

```
            Process pdfprocess = new Process();
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\xyz\Desktop\dgdfg\PdfReportGeneration\bin\Debug\PdfReportGeneration.exe";

            pdfprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pdfprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pdfprocess.Start();
```

But invoking other application like

```
 pdfprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
```

works fine.
What will be the reason?

Comment: You can write your pdf generation code in window service it self.

Comment: i tried that didnt work so i went to trigger a console app.Reason is we cannot use system.drawing.printing related classes in service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some permissions issue there (PdfReportGeneration.exe inaccessible under service account or maybe something that it uses...)
I would advise to capture Process Monitor log to see where exactly it fails.

Comment: How to log process events?

Answer (score 1):

Windows services run in a different window station and cannot interact with the desktop, unless you're using an older version of Windows and tick a checkbox in the service properties in the service manager.

Comment: am using Windows XP and in the process properties i did check "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Comment: What credentials do you use for the service?

Comment: Local system as an administrator!

Comment: To find out if it's a security issue, try running the service with your own credentials, and also try running the console application with the system account (Sysinternals PsExec can do that).

Comment: Can you please provide me some links on same? i tried some but more of confused!